# Changing the model after tapping a UIButton in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am looking for is a clean way of changing the model after tapping a button in a custom cell. It's tapping the button that matters here and not selecting the row, so `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't what I am interested in.

For example

```
let array = [true, false, true]
```

When the user taps the button in the second cell, the model should become

```
array[1] = true
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` a target action is added to the button :

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "myAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

the action looks like :

```
func myAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        //how to change the model and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths since the sender is just a UIButton!?
    }
```

Comment: each cell contains a button

Comment: yes it is a property/subview of the custom cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one section in the tableViewController, you could always set `button.tag = [indexPath row]` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then your action would always know which row was touched from the `sender.tag` value.  Quick and dirty, but it would work.

Or, if you will reuse this custom cell in tableviews with multiple sections, you could subclass the UIButton and add a property for the indexPath.  Then you would always have access to both section and row values. Personally, I would take this approach because it gives you the most flexibility in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

inside of **cellForRowAtIndexPath()**

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then inside of your function **myAction()**

```
 func myAction(sender:UIButton)
 {

   var index = sender.view.tag
    array[index] = true  // just like you want 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear about your question - are you asking how you can change a uitableviewcell's content once a button is pressed in the cell then one way to go about it would be to tag the button with the cell's indexPath when the cell is created in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  Then you can read the tag from the selector once the button is pushed.

I just tested this and it works.  When you create the cell add the line:

```
cell.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and then in the selector method for the button you can use:

```
NSInteger p=sender.tag;
int x=(int)p;
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

In my example I changed the background color of the cell that the pressed button was in.